# Get ancestor node number with ete3

Tags: python, phylogeny, ete3

I would need to get the node number within a tree in ete3.

Here is an example of a tree:

```
rooted_tree = Tree( "((A,B),(C,D));" )

print rooted_tree
#
#          /-A
#     /---|
#    |     \-B
#----|
#    |     /-C
#     \---|
#          \-D
```

then I calculate some stuff from this tree (not important for the question), and this stuff gives me values for each node in the tree, which then I plot in ggplot tree. But ggplot tree need the node number to plot this information, the problem here is that I cannot manage to find the code in order to get the node number of the tree `"rooted_tree"`

Let say I want the node number of the ancestor of `A` and `B` , how can I get it ? I only know to do that:

```
ancestor = tree.get_common_ancestor("A","B")
```

but something like `ancestor.num` of `ancestor.node_number` does not work...

Answer (score 2):

all the nodes in ete tree are objects, they don't have a number but they have a hash ID labeled for topological perspect

you can access those topology id by

```
ancestor = tree.get_common_ancestor("A","B")
print(ancestor.get_topology_id())
```

quote from ete3 documentation:

> get_topology_id(attr='name') New in version 2.3.
>
> Returns the unique ID representing the topology of the current tree.
> Two trees with the same topology will produce the same id. If trees
> are unrooted, make sure that the root node is not binary or use the
> tree.unroot() function before generating the topology id.
>
> This is useful to detect the number of unique topologies over a bunch
> of trees, without requiring full distance methods.
>
> The id is, by default, calculated based on the terminal node’s names.
> Any other node attribute could be used instead.

further reference:
http://etetoolkit.org/docs/latest/reference/reference_tree.html#get_topology_id